# How to do a join to get previous days values?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to join tables as follow:

| Report_Period | Entity | Tag | Users Count | Report_Period_M-1 | Report_Period_D-1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-31 | entity 1 | X | 471 | 2017-05-31 | 2021-03-18 | ... |
| 2020-12-31 | entity 2 | A | 135 | 2020-11-30 | 2021-03-18 | ... |
| 2020-11-30 | entity 3 | X | 402 | 2020-10-31 | 2021-03-18 | ... |

With a view containing Day - 1 results as follow :

| Report_Period | Entity | Tag | Users Count | Report_Period_D-1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-31 | entity 1 | X | 445 | 2021-03-18 |
| 2021-03-31 | entity 2 | A | 135 | 2021-03-18 |
| 2021-03-31 | entity 3 | X | 402 | 2021-03-18 |

My Aim is at least to return results like this  :

| Report_Period | Entity | Tag | Users Count | Users Count D-1 | Report_Period_M-1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-31 | entity 1 | X | 471 | 445 | 2021-02-28 | ... |
| 2020-12-31 | entity 2 | A | 135 | NULL | 2020-11-30 | ... |
| 2020-11-30 | entity 3 | X | 402 | NULL | 2020-10-31 | ... |

If i use classic joins on Report_Period,Entity & Tag,
i will only return results rows which contains report period 2021-03-31.

Is it possible to replace the users count values for the current period ?
If i want to replace Users Count values with Users Count D-1 for the current month ?

Your help is welcome and thank you for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example it just looks like you want a LEFT JOIN

```
WITH table_a(report_period, entity, tag, users_count, report_period_m1, report_period_d1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('2021-03-31', 'entity 1','X',471,'2017-05-31','2021-03-18'),
    ('2020-12-31', 'entity 2','A',135,'2020-11-30','2021-03-18'),
    ('2020-11-30', 'entity 3','X',402,'2020-10-31','2021-03-18')
), table_b(report_period, entity, tag, users_count, report_period_d1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('2021-03-31','entity 1','X',445, '2021-03-18'),
    ('2021-03-31','entity 2','A',135, '2021-03-18'),
    ('2021-03-31','entity 3','X',402, '2021-03-18')
)
SELECT a.*
    ,b.*
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
    ON a.report_period = b.report_period AND a.entity = b.entity
ORDER BY 1 desc, 2;
```

gives:

```
REPORT_PERIOD   ENTITY      TAG   USERS_COUNT   REPORT_PERIOD_M1    REPORT_PERIOD_D1    REPORT_PERIOD   ENTITY      TAG   USERS_COUNT   REPORT_PERIOD_D1
2021-03-31      entity 1    X     471           2017-05-31          2021-03-18          2021-03-31      entity 1    X     445           2021-03-18
2020-12-31      entity 2    A     135           2020-11-30          2021-03-18          null            null        null  null           null
2020-11-30      entity 3    X     402           2020-10-31          2021-03-18          null            null        null  null           null
```

But for the statement of "replacing values" I can but assume you mean you then want to COALESCE `b.users_count` with `a.users_count` when `b` did not match thus the code becomes..

```
WITH table_a(report_period, entity, tag, users_count, report_period_m1, report_period_d1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('2021-03-31', 'entity 1','X',471,'2017-05-31','2021-03-18'),
    ('2020-12-31', 'entity 2','A',135,'2020-11-30','2021-03-18'),
    ('2020-11-30', 'entity 3','X',402,'2020-10-31','2021-03-18')
), table_b(report_period, entity, tag, users_count, report_period_d1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES

    ('2021-03-31','entity 1','X',445, '2021-03-18'),
    ('2021-03-31','entity 2','A',135, '2021-03-18'),
    ('2021-03-31','entity 3','X',402, '2021-03-18')
)
SELECT a.*
    ,COALESCE(b.USERS_COUNT, a.USERS_COUNT) as b_USERS_COUNT
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
    ON a.report_period = b.report_period AND a.entity = b.entity
ORDER BY 1,2;
```